# Combining Java 8 lambda predicates with logical operators

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `Stream<SomeClass> stream` whereas `SomeClass` has boolean methods `isFoo()` and `isBar()`.

I'd like to check that all elements in the stream have both `isFoo()` and `isBar()` equals to `true`. I can check this conditions individually via `SomeClass:isFoo` and `SomeClass::isBar` lambdas.

But how would I combine these two lambdas with a logical operator like `and`/`&&`?

One obvious way is to write an extra lambda:

```
stream.allMatch(item -> item.isFoo() && item.isBar());
```

But I'd like to avoid writing an extra lambda.

Another way is to cast to `Predicate<? super SomeClass>`:

```
stream.allMatch(((Predicate<? super SomeClass>) SomeClass::isFoo).and(SomeClass::isBar));
```

Is there a better way - without casts and explicit lambdas?

Comment: Why would you like to avoid writing an extra lambda?  You can do two `.filter()` but you would need lambdas there too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How would I combine two `filter`s to get `allMatch` functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there were a hypothetical `Predicate.of` method, you could write:

```
stream.allMatch(Predicate.of(SomeClass::isFoo).or(SomeClass::isBar));
```

It doesn't exist, but you could write it yourself.

```
public final class Predicates {
    public static <T> Predicate<T> of(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

That said, I would personally go with your first option.

```
stream.allMatch(item -> item.isFoo() && item.isBar());
```

`::` method references are nice but sometimes you have to write explicit lambdas.

Answer (score 12):

This might not qualify as the answer (please don't up vote it if it does not), but I *sort of* had the same need, to munch together some predicates and I just wrote a small utility for that.

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> andPredicates(Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    return Arrays.stream(predicates).reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true);
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. OP is looking to not combine lambdas with `&&`, but it's trivial to wrap the lambdas in a `Predicate<T>` and then apply this answer.

Comment: This will fail if predicates is empty.

Comment: @whiskeysierra good point! I guess `orElse` would suffice here

Answer (score 1):

You could filter and only collect the size of the list and compare with the original list :

`long count = list.stream().filter(SomeClass::isFoo).filter(SomeClass::isBar).collect(Collectors.counting());`

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the **filter** method of Stream. Filter select the elements of the list that match the given predicate.

This line select the elements which are Foo AND Bar at the same time:

```
list.stream().filter(SomeClass::isFoo).filter(SomeClass::isBar)
```

The output is a Stream, so you should collect the elements in a List to actually use them:

```
 list.stream().filter(SomeClass::isFoo).filter(SomeClass::isBar).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

In order to check if all the elements of the stream are both Foo and Bar, you could compare the size of the original list with the size of the filtered stream:

```
public static Boolean isFooBar(List<SomeClass> list) {
    return list.size() == list.stream().filter(SomeClass::isFoo).filter(SomeClass::isBar).count();
}
```

Comment: I don't need to select `isFoo()` and `isBar()` elements, I need to check if *all* elements of the stream are both `isFoo()` and `isBar()`.

Comment: Then you could simply compare the size of the original list with the size of the filtered list, see my edit.

Comment: This looks really suboptimal.